# PCI (no express) GPUs

Tags: litecoin, gpu-mining, mining-setup

I have a mining rig, with 2 PCIe (already being used) and 4 PCIs without use. I was thinking to buy a PCI based ATI card like http://www.club-3d.com/index.php/products/reader.en/product/radeon-hd-5450-pci-noiseless-edition.html but I was wondering if anybody has experience running PCI GPUs to mine.

EDIT: to avoid off-topic:

I'm not interested in FPGA or ASIC. I just want to know if the card cited is able to, for example, do opencl.

Comment: With regards to mining: Use FPGAs, ASICs, or don't bother.

Comment: please avoid useless comments. Altcoins are there, specially litecoin and FPGA and ASIC aren't useful. BTW how many miners do you know with ASIC? Are you still waiting for a butterfly device? :)

Answer (score 3):

You can actually pick up a PCI to PCI-E 1x (open end) adapter and plug in any video card you want. Then use a PCI-E 1x to 16x adapter. This is an example, but there are cheaper ones out there.

http://www.quill.com/startech-pci-cards/cbs/352874.html?cm_mmc=SEM_PLA_T_352874

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no.  The ' PCI ' card in that link is a PCIx16.  The PCI standard ( usualy white colored slots ) is really slow compared to the short PCIx1 ( usually short black ) slots.  I have looked in to those ' adapters ' for PCI to PCIE and they slow down the connection further.  I also have a few PCIx16 v2.0 cards that are not recognised on any motherboard that is either PCIx16 v1.0a, v1.0.  and no amount of jumpers, adapters, etc will ever get them recognised due to how the motherboard manufacturer updates their BIOS due to wiring for the difference between the versions.  It is cheaper, faster and easier to set up another motherboard ( with the adapter from the short to long x16 slots ) to get a second mining rig going.  I have hardware experience and enough old motherboards given to me that if there was a way to ' plug in ' a mining card to the PCI slot ( with or with out adapters ) and guarantee that it would work, there would be a link to youtube showing how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

the best way to use your pci slot is to get a pci usb hub card, and line up the asic usb erupters hubs on that. if your mother board has 4 usb ports and you hook a hub to each one and each hub has 7 asic miners, adding the card will double that. then do the other slots and keep going, before you know it you will be tera hashing!

Comment: if you read again my question, it wasn't ASIC related, because mainly it was focused on LTC. If I had enough points I would -1 you... just saying